# Advantage of Using backtracking and branch and bound

Tags: performance, algorithm, complexity-theory, backtracking, branch-and-bound

I understand that DP gives a better performance for many NP complete problems like TSP. Though the space needed is large, it reduces the complexity well.

But I couldn't understand the efficiency of branch and bound and backtracking as compared to an brute force search.

In worst case whether brute force equals b&b or backtracking ?

Comment: By exhaustive search, you mean a brute force search?

Comment: @Gangadhar Changed to brute force search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With exhaustive search, you would compute all N! possible routes between the nodes. With backtracking, you might compute a route visiting half the nodes, notice that it is already more expensive than the best route found so far, and stop investigating that partial route at that point. By doing so, you have skipped computing all of the routes that are produced by completing that partial route, thus saving time over exhaustive search, which would have continued to check them all.

Comment: But in worst case both needs to check N! combinations!

Comment: @user567879: Correct. There is no silver bullet. The branch and bound solution helps on *average* case, not *worst* case.

Comment: I don't know of good worst case bounds for branch and bound on the TSP. All of the writeups I have seen (which use better choices of what to branch on and better bounding functions than my over-simplified example) concentrate on expected behaviour, typically analysed by computer experiment. However these experiments do show that careful branch and bound can do a lot better in practice that brute force - the example at http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/sweden/compute/compute.htm - which also uses some hand tuning - caught my eye.

Comment: @amit Then whats is the main advantage?

Comment: @user567879: The main advantage is that it (1) doesn't perform worse then naive brute-force. (2) Usually performs better then naive brute-force. There is really no cons to using branch and bound when implementing an exhaustive search solution.